# Alternatives to org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics

Tags: xjc, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I need to generate Java classes using XJC plugin (in gradle) with `toString` implementation. I am using `org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics` library, however this needs to be added as a runtime dependency to work since the plugin is actually adding a `ToString2` interface to the generated java classes.

The problem is that this library brings in `com.google.code.javaparser:javaparser:1.0.11` dependency along with it and this has GPLv3 license which I want to avoid.

What alternatives do I have to achieve the same?